# My proof of $\sup(A\cup B)=\sup\{\sup(A),\sup(B)\}$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-verification

> Let $(X,\le)$ a partially ordered set, and $A$ and $B$ nonempty subsets of $X$ such that $A$ and $B$ are bounded above. And suppose that the relevant suprema exist.
>
> 1. Prove that
>
> $$\sup(A\cup B)=\sup\{\sup(A),\sup(B)\}\tag{1}$$
>
> 2. Show that, in general, we cant strengthen the statement $(1)$ to
>
> $$\sup(A\cup B)=\max\{\sup(A),\sup(B)\}$$
>
> (hint: consider the power set of a nonempty set.)

I want to check my proof, it seems not completely correct. From the definitions we have that

$$\sup(A\cup B)=\min\{x\in X:x\ge y,\forall y\in A\cup B\}$$

and

$$\sup\{\sup(A),\sup(B)\}=\min\{x\in X:(x\ge\sup(A))\land (x\ge\sup(B))\}$$

So we must show that

$$\{x\in X: x\ge y,\forall y\in A\cup B\}= \{x\in X:(x\ge\sup(A))\land (x\ge\sup(B))\}$$

**First inclusion**. I will notate $x\ge y,\forall y\in D$ as just $x\ge D$. Then if $x\ge A\cup B$ we have that $x\ge A\land x\ge B$.

To show that $x\ge A\cup B\implies (x\ge A)\land(x\ge B)$ we only must show that if $x\ge A\cup B$ then $x\ge A$ because $A\subseteq A\cup B$. The same for $B$.

Then if $x\ge A$ then $x\in\{y:y\ge\min\{z\ge A\}\}=\{y:y\ge\sup(A)\}$, and in the same way $x\in\{y:y\ge\sup(B)\}$, then we have that

$$\{x\in X: x\ge y,\forall y\in A\cup B\}\subseteq \{x\in X:(x\ge\sup(A))\land (x\ge\sup(B))\}\tag{2}$$

**Second inclusion**. If $x\ge\sup(A)=\min\{z:z\ge A\}$ then $x\ge A$. Alternatively if $x\ge\sup(B)$ then $x\ge B$. Then if $x\ge A\land x\ge B$ this implies that $x\ge A\cup B$. So

$$\{x\in X:(x\ge\sup(A))\land (x\ge\sup(B))\}\subseteq \{x\in X: x\ge y,\forall y\in A\cup B\}\tag{3}$$

Then by $(2)$ and $(3)$ we have that $(1)$ is true.

---

For the second part we can see that for some $(\mathcal P(X),\subseteq)$ partial ordered set there is no maximum for some set $\{\sup(A),\sup(B)\}$.

Suppose that $\sup(A)=\{1,2,3\}$ and $\sup(B)=\{2,3,4\}$, then

$$\max\{\{1,2,3\},\{2,3,4\}\}$$

doesnt exist, but

$$\sup\{\{1,2,3\},\{2,3,4\}\}=\{1,2,3,4\}$$

So, can you check what is wrong (if is something) in my exercise? Any advice will be very welcome. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Talking about posets, please avoid the use of $\wedge$ to mean "and"

Comment: @PaoloLeonetti why? There is a different meaning for $\land$ in the context of posets?

Comment: Yes, usually $x \wedge y$ stands for $\inf\{x,y\}$, provided it exists..

Comment: @PaoloLeonetti oh, ok... Idk that... Thank you for pointing it.

Comment: Please edit the notation $x \in \{x: x\ge \min\{z\ge A\}\}$, it doesn't make much sense to have $x$ inside and outside the brackets

Comment: However, the solution looks fine to me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A shorter way for the first part: $\sup A \le \sup A\cup B$ and similarly $\sup B \le \sup A\cup B$. Therefore
$$
\sup A \vee \sup B \le \sup A\cup B.
$$

Conversely, fix $x=\sup A \vee \sup B$. Then $x \ge a$ and $x \ge b$ for each $a \in A$ and $b \in B$. Hence $x \ge \sup A\cup B$.

Comment: I must understand the symbol $\lor$ as $\sup$, right?

Comment: @Masacroso right